# Replacing cells in spark dataframe Efficently with Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, outliers

My main objective is, finding the outliers and replacing these values with the 'None' so in the next stage process will apply imputation.

Spark dataframe is looking like this. (The real data I work with have more than 10M rows and I execute this code on databricks)

| store_id | channel | prod | conditions_key | Variable1 | Variable2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Store1 | A | 1 | Yes | 10000 | 900 |
| Store2 | A | 1 | Yes | 10 | 800 |
| Store3 | A | 1 | Yes | 500 | 700 |
| Store4 | B | 2 | Yes | 5000 | 600 |
| Store5 | B | 2 | Yes | 100000 | 300 |
| Store6 | A | 1 | No | 10000 | 900 |
| Store7 | A | 1 | No | 10 | 800 |
| Store8 | A | 1 | No | 500 | 700 |
| Store9 | B | 2 | No | 5000 | 600 |
| Store0 | B | 2 | No | 100000 | 300 |

It only needs to detect outlier if conditions_key == 'Yes'
and detection needs to be by prod and channel level.

I typed the code that handles it but it takes a very long time to finish.
I guess doing it this way is not efficient (since I'm looping over spark dataframe over and over), and I couldn't think any other way of doing it.

I would be grateful if somebody can show me a better way of doing this or help me making this code efficient.

I'm sharing the code below. Hope the information I shared is enough.

Thanks & Regards,

outlier_vars_to_check = ['Variable1', 'Variable2'],
combined_sdf = the dummy data

```
for outlier_var in outlier_vars_to_check:
    percentile1 = F.expr(f'percentile_approx({outlier_var}, 0.25)')
    percentile2 = F.expr(f'percentile_approx({outlier_var}, 0.50)')
    percentile3 = F.expr(f'percentile_approx({outlier_var}, 0.75)')

    # Quartile calculation
    grp_quartile_sdf = combined_sdf.filter(F.col('conditions_key') == 'Yes') \
                                   .groupBy('prod', 'channel').agg(percentile1.alias('q1'),
                                                                   percentile2.alias('q2'),
                                                                   percentile3.alias('q3'))
    # Adding calculated quartile for each prod and market to the dictionary
    outlier_dict.update({outlier_var: grp_quartile_sdf.withColumn('iqr', F.col('q3') - F.col('q1'))
                                                      .withColumn('lbound', F.col('q1') - 3*F.col('iqr'))
                                                      .withColumn('ubound', F.col('q1') + 3*F.col('iqr'))
                                                      .toPandas().to_dict('records')})

for out_key in outlier_dict.keys():
    count_before = combined_sdf.select(out_key).filter((F.col('conditions_key') == 'Yes') &
                                                       (F.col(out_key).isNull())).count()
    for dict_index in range(len(outlier_dict.get(out_key))):
        # Prod, bygroup_id, lower bound, upper bound.
        prod = outlier_dict.get(out_key)[dict_index]['prod']
        chnl = outlier_dict.get(out_key)[dict_index]['channel']
        lbound = outlier_dict.get(out_key)[dict_index]['lbound']
        ubound = outlier_dict.get(out_key)[dict_index]['ubound']
        combined_sdf = combined_sdf.withColumn(out_key, F.when((F.col('prod') == prod) &
                                                               (F.col('channel') == chnl) &
                                                               (F.col('conditions_key') == 'Yes') &
                                                               ((F.col(out_key) <= lbound) |
                                                                (F.col(out_key) >= ubound)), F.lit(None))
                                                         .otherwise(combined_sdf[out_key]))

    count_after = combined_sdf.select(out_key).filter((F.col('conditions_key') == 'Yes') &
                                                      (F.col(out_key).isNull())).count()
    if count_after - count_before > 0:
        print(f'For {out_key} detected outliers {count_after - count_before}')

combined_sdf.persist()
print('Outlier detection completed! ')
```

Comment: based on the shared code, you calculate percentiles & bounds only for "Yes" in conditions_key, but apply the bounds on the overall data -- `combined_sdf = combined_sdf.withColumn(...)`

Comment: Yes, you are right. in the original I have it in though. I will edit the part now.